# How to move text to end of box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I created two flex boxes. The box on the left displays an image. The box on the right displays text but it must be displayed at the end of the box.

```css
.Details {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline;
}

p span {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.End {
  display: inline;
}

.End {
  display: flex;
}

.End.img {
  justify-content: left;
}

.End.p {
  justify-content: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="End">
  <img src="http://www.intro-webdesign.com/images/newlogo.png">
  <div id="BLOCK">
    <p>This page was created by <span class="MyName">nameh dhreh</span> and Colleen Van Lent.To learn more about web design, visit <a href="http://www.intro-webdesign.com">Intro To Web Design</a>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you know with the end of the box?! The lower right corner?

Answer (score 0):

add `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
.Details {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline;
}

p span {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.End {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="End">
  <img src="http://www.intro-webdesign.com/images/newlogo.png">
  <div id="BLOCK">
    <p>This page was created by <span class="MyName">My Name</span> and Colleen Van Lent.To learn more about web design, visit <a href="http://www.intro-webdesign.com
```

Comment: Are you sure he wants horizontal or vertical end?

Comment: In question it says left and right so most probably horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to align text right by 'end of the box' -

```css
.Details {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline;
}

p span {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.End {
  display: inline;
}

.End {
  display: flex;
}

.End.img {
  justify-content: left;
}

.End.p {
  justify-content: right;
}

#BLOCK {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="End">
  <img src="http://www.intro-webdesign.com/images/newlogo.png">
  <div id="BLOCK">
    <p>This page was created by <span class="MyName">Madiha Gurchani</span> and Colleen Van Lent.To learn more about web design, visit <a href="http://www.intro-webdesign.com">Intro To Web Design</a>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```